# A riddle for a kid

Tags: riddle

Here goes the riddle:

> I never do offend you
>
> Yet you always whip me,
>
> Which do not amend me,
>
> Though I dance and skip ;
>
> When I'm upright you do like
>   me best,
>
> And severely do whip me
>   when I want to rest.

What am I?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are

> a spinning top.

(Because

> an old-fashioned spinning top is made to spin by a sort of whipping motion, which needs to be renewed once it starts to slow down and therefore stand less vertical as it spins.)

Comment: So the dance in question is [The Whirling Devishes Dance](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a7/Whirling_Dervishes_at_Calgary_Turkish_Festival.jpg).

Comment: And the dance part comes from the lyrics of the dreidle dreidle dreidle song.

Comment: @crayon, is this correct or not?

Answer (score -1):

You are

> A horse

because

> A horse can be whipped when it's tired to make it perform better, though never does it retaliate.